# How to Grab SSL Certificate in OpenSSL

Tags: c++, ssl, sed, openssl

So I have been searching high and low for how to validate my server's certificate from within OpenSSL in a C++ application I am developing, and I finally got a hint. However, I am still missing a few steps.

So I found out that OpenSSL has a ssl client application called s_client. When I use the following command:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.me:443  -debug | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > my.cert
```

I receive this error as I do within my application:

```
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

It's not until I did some more searching that I found out what the error meant and that I had to do the following:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.me:443  -debug | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > my.cert
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.me:443  -debug -CAfile my.cert
```

The first command connects, receives a response, saves it to a file, but fails to validate the response. The second reconnects sending the saved file and allows the certificate to be properly verified.

My question is, how can I grab the stream that is being send to sed and send "my.cert" in c/c++ preferably in one connect? I have been walking the s_client code but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.me:443  -debug
> ...
> I receive this error as I do within my application:
>
> verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
> ```

`mywebsite.me` is certifed by Go Daddy. In particular, `Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority`.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.me:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/O=breezi.com/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=breezi.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
...
```

Navigate to [Go Daddy Repository, SSL Certificate Information](https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.pki) and fetch [Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority Root Certificate](https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.pki?streamfilename=gd-class2-root.crt&actionMethod=anonymous%2Frepository.xhtml%3Arepository.streamFile%28%27%27%29&cid=634624). You can't do a simple `wget` with a URL because GoDaddy has f**k'd up the download with javascript (it fetches a web page rather then the certificate). The GoDaddy root is saved as `gd-class2-root.crt`.

Then, run `openssl s_client` again with the `-CAfile` option. The certificate is expired, so you'll receive `Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)`. But it clears the trust issue.

```
$ openssl s_client -CAfile gd-class2-root.crt -connect mywebsite.me:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority, serialNumber = 07969287
verify return:1
depth=0 O = breezi.com, OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = breezi.com
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Sep 29 02:23:46 2013 GMT
verify return:1
depth=0 O = breezi.com, OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = breezi.com
notAfter=Sep 29 02:23:46 2013 GMT
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/O=breezi.com/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=breezi.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/O=breezi.com/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=breezi.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4497 bytes and written 518 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: zlib compression
Expansion: zlib compression
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 41C9F384CAB44419C20452CCBD7B7346A224F55906F943DD977198B48B44FC33
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: BAD61F7C0883D5C3918DCB766C83A85FFF4C533823C5CA41C62617701E87C66C6D1351C30521B337267753B16C830BBD
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 77 82 b3 42 d2 32 f9 4f-32 55 ea 03 0a 0f 66 16   w..B.2.O2U....f.
    0010 - 97 8f 93 2e 47 4e ae cc-d2 a8 c0 ee 81 47 63 be   ....GN.......Gc.
    0020 - 07 40 fc c4 a0 28 78 e6-a2 97 22 73 87 28 77 f2   .@...(x..."s.(w.
    0030 - a2 80 a3 6f d3 3c 50 cc-82 a8 0c 8e 9b 04 f0 7e   ...o.<P........~
    0040 - 12 24 d2 2a 9c 6b ef b8-49 d7 16 f1 45 80 e1 44   .$.*.k..I...E..D
    0050 - fe d4 87 0e 92 80 b3 63-98 36 5e 9b 39 91 a3 76   .......c.6^.9..v
    0060 - 3a 37 dc 1b 4d de 7e 01-22 d0 cd c0 7a 4c cf f8   :7..M.~."...zL..
    0070 - ae d4 a5 fe 74 19 03 db-99 28 b7 09 ce 08 35 dd   ....t....(....5.
    0080 - 33 ff cd 9f 88 63 05 8a-f4 d1 f7 32 16 0b ed b9   3....c.....2....
    0090 - 9f b4 ee 53 2d 8b b4 c2-27 bd b5 4d e3 19 a3 72   ...S-...'..M...r

    Compression: 1 (zlib compression)
    Start Time: 1393884832
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)
```

---

> ```
> It's not until I did some more searching that I found out
> what the error meant and that I had to do the following:
> echo -n | openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.me:443  -debug | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > my.cert
> echo -n | openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.me:443  -debug -CAfile my.cert
> ```

No, this is not the way to do things.

---

If you own the `mywebsite.me` domain, then you can get a free Class 1 certificate from [StartCom](http://www.startcom.org/). Their certifcates are trusted by most mobile and desktop browsers.

While StartCom does not charge to issue the certificate, they do charge for revocation because that's what costs money. (Other CAs charge you for the revocation up front and then pocket the money if not needed).

Comment: I wasn't expecting mywebsite.me to actually be owned lol. Thank you for the fast response, but I need to handle a 20 error like if you were to use google.com, and I need to handle this in c++. I want to stay away from including files in my builds, I would like to connect grab the cert and use it to validate the server. Thanks again.

Comment: "I wasn't expecting mywebsite.me to actually be owned..." - next time use `example.com`. Its reserved by IANA for that purpose.

Comment: What would be the proper way to validate the certificate? Do you have any references? Thanks!