# Can't verify CA certificate unless CApath or CAfile used

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, ldap

Im having trouble with having OpenSSL connect to a server because of trust issues. I placed the CA  certificate on `/etc/ssl/certs/` and have run `sudo c_rehash` and can see that the correct file has been made. I can see that CA certificate is in the ca-certificates.crt. However if I run:

```
openssl s_client -connect servername.domain.com:636
```

The command fails with Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)

If I do:

```
openssl s_client -connect servername.domain.com:636 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

I get Verify return code: 0 (ok)

What can I do so I dont have to specify the CApath?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> OpenSSL connect to a server because of trust issues.

Unlike browsers, which trust nearly everything from anybody, OpenSSL trusts nothing by default.

Its up to you to determine what should be trusted. You will have to specify something when using OpenSSL and `s_client`.

If you are working programmatically with the OpenSSL API, you have more options. But this appears to be related to using the OpenSSL commands.

---

> What can I do so I don't have to specify the `CApath`?

You can use the `CAfile`. It avoids the rehash, and it creates a 1:1 mapping for trust of the domain. That is, you only trust one issuer for the domain in question. If any other issuer claims to be the issuer, you won't trust the issuer or the server.

You can see how to extract the needed info from OpenSSL's `s_client` and use `CAfile` at [How to Grab SSL Certificate in OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152831/how-to-grab-ssl-certificate-in-openssl/22158697).

When using all the certificates present in `CAPath`, you trust any issuer, even if its not the real issuer. This has happened in the past and its bad.

The corner case is where a bad guy compromises the CA you trust and issues phony certifcates for the domain. This has happened in the past too, and its bad.

In the two negative cases above, you can forgo conferring trust to DNS and CAs and use a security diversification technique like certificate or public key pinning. If there's a pre-existing relationship between you and the site, then you know the expected public key of the server. In this case, there's no need to trust a CA.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was starting to go crazy. I thought there would be a way to verify the cert without having to specify the path or the cert itself (works fine if I specify either). Now I just have to figure out why my application (mediawiki) isn't binding using that cert even though I specify the path and file.

Comment: See my answer below - using export the application may use the intended file/directory.

Comment: Specifying a CApath or CAfile additionally loads CA certificates from default
location, unless SSL_CERT_DIR is set it seems.

See [openssl bug #2936](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2936#txn-28848)

Comment: The @krayon link no longer works but https://security.stackexchange.com/a/142172 has a different bug number, from which I can find the code at issue in https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-dev/2015-February/000678.html, from which I can see the fix at https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/70e5fd877890489a3972bf8bf50bfec1fca3875e, and so we learn that this seemingly wasn't a policy to trust no one by default, contra jww, but just a whoopsie.  Changing the default trust policy, you'd think that'd make the release notes, no?  Oh well, it was only s_client.

Answer (score 14):

You can also set and export the environment variables SSL_CERT_FILE or SSL_CERT_DIR...

`export SSL_CERT_FILE=/path/to/ca_bundle.crt`

`export SSL_CERT_DIR=/path/to/ca/dir`

Then you do not have to specify CAfile or CApath in every openssl command.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the CA file or CA path in a configuration file, like `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly the question, you have to assign at your domain the certificate.

You could do that (on apache) into `/etc/httpd/vhost.d/servername.domain.com` (if you use vhosts)

```
SSLEngine On
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/yourcert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/yourcert.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/yourcert.ca-bundle
```

Comment: Your answer actually helps to resolve an web issue that has bothered me for a while. Thanks.