# Apache to weblogic ssl connection failure

Tags: apache, openssl, weblogic

Whenever a request comes to apache server it is not able to fulfill it. I am getting following error in apache error logs

```
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:02 2014] [info] [client 10.246.86.135] Connection to child 75 established (server myserver.com:443)
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:02 2014] [info] Seeding PRNG with 1024 bytes of entropy
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:02 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1871): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:02 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1879): OpenSSL: Loop: before/accept initialization
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:02 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1947): OpenSSL: I/O error, 11 bytes expected to read on BIO#7f94c4001360 [mem: 7f950c024bd0]
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:02 2014] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1908): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv2/v3 read client hello A
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:02 2014] [info] [client 10.246.86.135] (70014)End of file found: SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!]
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:02 2014] [info] [client 10.246.86.135] Connection closed to child 75 with abortive shutdown (server myserver.com:443)
```

Tried to establish connectivity to server, got following outputs

```
user@server: openssl s_client -connect  10.246.86.142:8444 -state -nbio
CONNECTED(00000003)
turning on non blocking io
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
write R BLOCK
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
140342456735560:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:741:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 263 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

Also

```
user@server: wget https://10.246.86.142:8444 --debug
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.12 on linux-gnu.

--2014-11-21 17:57:39--  https://10.246.86.142:8444/
Connecting to 10.246.86.142:8444... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000001b6a2a0 (new refcount 0).
Deleting unused 0x0000000001b6a2a0.
Initiating SSL handshake.
SSL handshake failed.
OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Closed fd 3
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Any ideas, what might be going wrong? All the certificates are in place and are valid

Comment: When you're running openssl, have you tried it with `CAFile` or `CAPath`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304564/cant-verify-ca-certificate-unless-capath-or-cafile-used

Comment: Have you enabled the plugin for apache and weblogic? Also I believe you may need a CA signed certificate. You will need to change the settings to be able to use self-signed certificates.

Comment: @name I tried with CAfile and CApath, still its the same issue.

Comment: @TheCurioustraveller Plugin is enabled and CA trusted certificate path is also provided in the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the issue with certificate at the weblogic end. Certificate was missing key usage 'key encipherment'

When certificate with key encipherment usage was imported at weblogic end, the connection was successful.